# How do you make consecutive if statements?

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

I have been learning to code in python and I've come up with a good idea for a program. The basis is the following:

```
if input() == 'unnamed variable':
   print('this')
if input() == 'another unnamed variable'
   print('this other response')
```

I cannot type in another unnamed variable without first satisfying the first if statement

I want my program to print something different for the user to read based on the input

How do I used consecutive if statements? I've tried elif and else. Am I able to have say 80 if statements back to back?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but you could use a loop and put `continue` statements in your conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do different things depending on the user input, then first of all, you should only ask the user to enter things once. So you should only call `input()` once and save the response to a variable:

```
response = input()
```

Then, you can use `if`, `elif` and `else` to check multiple different conditions and do different things each time:

```
if response == 'some input':
    print('User entered some input')
elif response == 'some other input':
    print('User entered some input')
elif response == 'some even more different input':
    print('User entered some even more different input')
else:
    print('User entered something I do not recognize')
```

So you only ask the user once and store the response, and then you compare the response against a number of different values: If one of the conditions is true, that part is executed and the remaining conditional checks are skipped.

Comment: thanks, much smarter way of writing it and it serves my purpose. Thank you for the tip. I'm looking up how to continue the code instead of it ending after print

Answer (score 0):

You can replace nested if -elif-elif-else by 'or'

```
if cond1 or cond2 or cond3
```

You can replace nested if-if-if by 'and'

```
if cond1 and cond2 and cond3
```

it may help you in redesigning big if-else chain

Answer (score 0):

You can define the input, and then check for equality.

```
userInput = input(" > ")
aNumber = 5
if userInput == 'y' or userInput == 'yes':
    print("You said yes!")
elif userInput == 'no':
    print("You said no.")
elif userInput == 'maybe' and aNumber == 5:
    print("you said maybe, and aNumber is equal to 5!")
else:
    print("I can't understand you.")
```